# Highlight found node in angular material tree

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this method to expand and highlight a specific node in my material tree:

```
    expand(folderId: number): any {
       for (let i = 0; i < this.treeControl.dataNodes.length; i++) 
       {
         if (this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].id == folderId) 
         {
           this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i]);
           hightlight(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i]);
         }
       }    
    }
```

here is my material tree structure:

```
 private _transformer = (node: Folder, level: number) => {
    return {
      expandable: !!node.children && node.children.length > 0,
      id: node.id,
      name: node.name,
      level: level,
    };
  };

  treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<ExampleFlatNode>(
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable,
  );

    treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
    this._transformer,
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable,
    node => node.children,
  );
  dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);
```

here is my mat tree template:

```
<mat-tree #inboxFolders [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding (contextmenu)="onContextmenu(node)"
    (click)="onNodeClick(node,$event)" class="treeNode" [cdkContextMenuTriggerFor]="inboxFolderContextMenu"
    id="{{node.name}}">        
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding (contextmenu)="onContextmenu(node)"
    (ngclick)="onNodeClick(node,$event)" id="{{node.name}}" class="treeNode"
    [cdkContextMenuTriggerFor]="inboxFolderContextMenu">
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

how should be highlight method in typescript to highlight the node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem in following way:

first, I wrote a highlight function as follow:

```
  highlightFolder() {

    for (let i = 0; i < this.treeControl.dataNodes.length; i++) {
      if (this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].id == this.clickedRow.folderId) {

        var pNode = this.getParentNode(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i]);

        this.treeControl.collapseAll();

        if (pNode) {
          this.treeControl.expand(pNode);
        }

        if (this.preClicked !== undefined) {
          this.preClicked.setAttribute("style", "background-color:none; font-weight: unset;");
        }

        this.preClicked = document.getElementById(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].name);

        const element = document.getElementById(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].name);
        element?.setAttribute("style", "background-color:#F6E8EC; font-weight: bold;");
        element?.scrollIntoView({ block: 'center' });
      }
    }
  }
```

then I wrote a method to find parent node of a node:

```
  getParentNode(node: any): any | null {
    const currentLevel = this.
      _getLevel(node);

    if (currentLevel < 1) {
      return null;
    }

    const startIndex = this.treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf(node) - 1;

    for (let i = startIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
      const currentNode = this.treeControl.dataNodes[i];

      if (this._getLevel(currentNode) < currentLevel) {
        return currentNode;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and finally, I call the highlight method inside mat table row click:

```
clickedRow: InboxItem = new InboxItem;
foundFolder: boolean = false;
onTableRowClick(row: InboxItem) {
    this.clickedRow.folderId = row.folderId;

    this.highlightFolder();
    this.foundFolder = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a highlight property to FlatNode interface, and update the same property  when highlight method is called

```
interface ExampleFlatNode {
  expandable: boolean;
  name: string;
  level: number;
  highlight: boolean;
}

highlight(node: ExampleFlatNode){
  node.highlight = true
}
```

now use this highlight property to apply a class on the mat-tree-node element in the HTML

```html
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" [ngClass]="{'highlight': node.highlight}">
...
</mat-tree-node>
```

```css
.highlight{
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: this code highlights just parent node, not the node itself

Comment: the node passed to the highlight method is not being highlighted? hightlight(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i])?

Comment: unfortunately, not, just a parent node being highlighted

Comment: please see my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751121/how-do-i-programmatically-focus-and-highlight-a-particular-material-tree-node

Comment: could you share the template code?

Comment: yes, I updated my question and added my mat tree template...

Comment: where is expand being called?

Comment: on material table row click: (click)="onTableRowClick(row)"

Comment: onTableRowClick(row: InboxItem) {
    this.expand(row.folderId);
    this.foundFolder = false;
}