# How do I programmatically focus and highlight a particular Material Tree node

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use following recursive function to find a node inside material tree by its Id:

```
foundFolder: boolean = false;

  expand(folderId: number): any {

    this.treeControl.dataNodes.forEach(_node => {
      if (_node.id === folderId && !this.foundFolder) {
        this.treeControl.collapseAll();
        this.treeControl.expandDescendants(_node);
                
        const element = document.getElementById(_node.name);
        element?.setAttribute("style", "background-color:#F6E8EC;");

        this.foundFolder = true;
      }
      else if (_node.expandable && !this.foundFolder && _node.children.find(c => c.id === folderId)) {
        this.expand(_node.id);
      }
    });

  }
```

> but this code just highlights parent node, not the actual child node
> itself. I need when I found the child node inside any parent I can
> focus and highlight exactly that node, not its parent node.

this is my mat tree structure:

```
interface ExampleFlatNode {
  id: number;
  expandable: boolean;
  name: string;
  level: number;
  children: Folder[];
  highlight: boolean;
}

private _transformer = (node: Folder, level: number) => {
    return {
      expandable: !!node.children && node.children.length > 0,
      id: node.id,
      name: node.name,
      level: level,
      children: node.children,
    };
  };

  treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<ExampleFlatNode>(
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable,
  );  

  treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
    this._transformer,
    node => node.level,
    node => node.expandable,
    node => node.children,
  );

  dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem in following way:

first, I wrote a highlight function as follow:

highlightFolder() {

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this.treeControl.dataNodes.length; i++) {
      if (this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].id == this.clickedRow.folderId) {

        var pNode = this.getParentNode(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i]);

        this.treeControl.collapseAll();

        if (pNode) {
          this.treeControl.expand(pNode);
        }

        if (this.preClicked !== undefined) {
          this.preClicked.setAttribute("style", "background-color:none; font-weight: unset;");
        }

        this.preClicked = document.getElementById(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].name);

        const element = document.getElementById(this.treeControl.dataNodes[i].name);
        element?.setAttribute("style", "background-color:#F6E8EC; font-weight: bold;");
        element?.scrollIntoView({ block: 'center' });
      }
    }
  }
```

then I wrote a method to find parent node of a node:

```
  getParentNode(node: any): any | null {
    const currentLevel = this.
      _getLevel(node);

    if (currentLevel < 1) {
      return null;
    }

    const startIndex = this.treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf(node) - 1;

    for (let i = startIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
      const currentNode = this.treeControl.dataNodes[i];

      if (this._getLevel(currentNode) < currentLevel) {
        return currentNode;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and finally, I call the highlight method inside mat table row click:

```
clickedRow: InboxItem = new InboxItem;
foundFolder: boolean = false;
onTableRowClick(row: InboxItem) {
    this.clickedRow.folderId = row.folderId;

    this.highlightFolder();
    this.foundFolder = false;
}
```